# php preg_match. change in subdomain to subfolder virtual

Tags: php, wildcard

sorry, I'm not good at php, this might be a very obvious mistake. I'm trying to this:

```
if(preg_match('#([a-z0-9-]+?)\.domain\.com#i', $servername, $blogname)){


    }   
        if ( check_suspend ( $blogname[0] ) ) {
        if(isset($_GET['id']) ){
            $res=mysql_query("select id,username from `feeds` where `id`=(select fid from `news_tmp` where `id`=$_GET[id]) limit 1");
            if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
                list($id,$username)=mysql_fetch_array($res);
                if($blogname[1]!=$username){
                    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
                    Header( "Location: http://$username.domain.com/post/$_GET[id]" ); 
                    exit;               
                }
            }
        }
```

I have link like : http://test313.domain.com/post/123456/

But I want to have url like http://domain.com/test313/post/123456/

I change

```
Header( "Location: http://$username.domain.com/post/$_GET[id]" );
```

to

```
Header( "Location: http://domain.com/$username/post/$_GET[id]" );
```

But page won't load. I think this is for line 1 > "preg_match".

Note : I enabled wildcard on my host. (Virtual subdomains)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first if-statement doesn't do anything if true. Is that intentional ?

Comment: What does "page won't load" mean? Is there a specific error message? Is the `if (preg_match) { }` block intentionally empty? Is this about missing RewriteRules perhaps? What's the exact value in `$servername` for the new virtual URL? (Also please read up on PDO / parameter binding - instead of variable interpolation for SQL queries.)

Comment: This check address url. if I remove this "if(preg_match" line then noting show in website.

Comment: @mario this means noting show In page reload. no. `code
if (preg_match) { }code` This check address url. if I remove this line then noting show in website after reload.
`code
 $servername = strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 $servername = (substr($servername,0,4) == 'www.')?substr($servername,4):$servername; code`


I don't understand your means about PDO?!